# #1005 - Can't create table 'EmployeeShifts' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

Here is the code below, I'm not sure what this error means...
All I know is that it has something to do with the employeeshifts table.
Does it have something to do with foreign keys?

(insterting this text as I have nothing else to say, but stack requires a lot of text)

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(45) NULL,
CustomerAddress VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Location (
Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Latitude VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT ' ',
Longitude VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Address));


CREATE TABLE Employee (
EmployeeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));


CREATE TABLE Truck (
LicensePlate CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
color VARCHAR(45) NULL,
capacity VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LicensePlate));

CREATE TABLE Shifts (
ShiftTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ShiftTime));

CREATE TABLE EmployeeShifts (
DesiredShift DATETIME NOT NULL,
EmployeeWorking VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
DateOfShift DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(DesiredShift, EmployeeWorking, DateOfShift),
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeWorking) REFERENCES Employee(Name),
FOREIGN KEY (DesiredShift) REFERENCES Shifts(ShiftTime));


CREATE TABLE Reservation (
ReservNum INT NOT NULL,
ReserveDate DATE NULL,
PickupTime VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
NumOfPassengers INT NULL,
sheduledTime VARCHAR(45) NULL,
ActualPickupTime VARCHAR(45),
ActualTime VARCHAR(45),
PricePaid VARCHAR(45),
DriverHourlyRate DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
PassEmployeeHourlyRate DECIMAL (7,2) NOT NULL,
DriverSalary VARCHAR(10),
PassEmployeeSalary VARCHAR(10),
Customer_CustomerID INT,
Truck_LicensePlate char(20) NOT NULL,
Employee_EmployeeID_Driver INT,
Location_Address_Pickup VARCHAR(100),
Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger INT,
Location_Address_Drop VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (ReservNum),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID),
FOREIGN KEY (Truck_LicensePlate) REFERENCES Truck (LicensePlate),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Driver) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Pickup) REFERENCES Location (Address),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Drop) REFERENCES Location (Address));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` column:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeShifts (
   DesiredShift DATETIME NOT NULL,
   EmployeeWorking VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,     
   DateOfShift DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY(DesiredShift, EmployeeWorking, DateOfShift),
   FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeWorking) REFERENCES Employee(Name), -- name is not UNIQUE/PK
   FOREIGN KEY (DesiredShift) REFERENCES Shifts(ShiftTime)
);
```

to:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeShifts ( 
   DesiredShift DATETIME NOT NULL,
   EmployeeID INT NOT NULL,   -- here
   DateOfShift DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY(DesiredShift, EmployeeID, DateOfShift), 
   FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
   FOREIGN KEY (DesiredShift) REFERENCES Shifts(ShiftTime)
);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f68ca1)**</kbd>